# Change color of geom_smooth based on fitted slope value

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm making a figure for a talk and want to do something a little strange for the sake of ease of presenting. I have 45 different groups that I want to show the variation in slope/intercepts for each group (I'm analyzing the real model with a mixed effect model).

I would like to colour my geom_smooth(method="lm", se=FALSE) lines based on a diverging continuous colour scheme based on the slope fits of the geom_smooth. I can't figure out how to mix continous color schemes with factors. Here is a reproducible example of the data I want to fit.

```
set.seed(9)
groups <- c(1:45)
family=as.factor(rep(groups, times=10))

x=abs(rnorm(450, mean=5, sd=8))
e=rnorm(450, mean=0, sd=3)
y=0.4+(-0.2*x)+e
df=data.frame(family, x, y)


ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, colour=family))+
   geom_point()+
   geom_smooth(method="lm", se=FALSE)+
   theme_classic()+
   theme(legend.position="null")
```

Comment: I would probably calculate the slopes outside of ggplot2 and then add them to the dataset for plotting. You can still get plots per group using `group` if you have a continuous `color`.  In terms of mixing factors and continuous colors, that's generally harder but you can use `fill` for points vs `color` for lines.

Answer (score 2):

First if you want gradient color, you should change `family` variable to numeric data type. Then you can pass any gradient palette to scale_color_gradient() as follows:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, color=as.numeric(family)))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(method="lm", se=FALSE)+
  scale_color_gradient(low = "white", high = "red") +
  theme_classic()+
  theme(legend.position="null")
```

[image]

Comment: You can use `group = family` to still get separate lines.